# Which is the official Spring Cloud Stream Apps source repository?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I'd like to add a new twitter user timeline source stream app to the Spring Cloud Stream Apps but I am a bit confused as to which source code to fork. There seems to be two source repositories for the Spring Cloud Stream Apps. There is this one (https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tree/master/spring-cloud-stream-app-dependencies) which seems to more closely correlate to the instructions in the documentation for creating and contributing your own [Stream Application Starters](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/1.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/_introduction.html#_contributing_stream_application_starters_and_generating_artifacts) but looks like it has been actively contributed to recently. There is also this set of repositories (https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=) which is the one linked to from the projects page and looks to be more active but doesn't match the documentation for contributing (e.g. there is no spring-"cloud-stream-app-dependencies" or "spring-cloud-stream-app-generator" modules).

So far, I believe the second place is likely the more up-to-date so I've forked from here (https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/twitter) and made my changes, but am looking for updated documentation before I submit as to make sure to be complete with my solution.

Which repository should I base my changes on and is there more up-to-date documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/twitter is the correct one.

You can check the announcement about this [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters#announcement-as-of-110rc1--avogadrorc1-release-this-project-is-now-moved-to-spring-cloud-stream-app-starters-organization-and-each-of-the-spring-cloud-stream-app-starters-is-now-maintained-in-a-separate-repo-by-itself)

Comment: Thank you. This is pretty much what i was looking for.